# Effect changes in the original .csproj file

Tags: c#, file-io, reference, msbuild, csproj

I am developing an application that would add/delete project properties and references from .csproj file as necessary.

```
project.AddItem("Reference", "System.IO", globalProperties);
project.AddItem("Reference", "System.Collections.Generic", globalProperties);
```

The above code adds the items.
When I print out the ProjectItems in project.Items, I am able to see the added references. When I open the .csproj file that needs to be modified, the changes are not visible (since the copy of the file is being passed).
However, I want to effect changes in the .csproj file that is being modified.
I tried using the "ref" keyword, but doesn't work.
Can someone tell me how to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a standard API for this? Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx

Comment: I am using that here, else I couldn't have accessed Project and ProjectCollection Classes...

Comment: So then just use the Save() method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have o add first an item group before your reference like that

```
var slItemGroup = project.Xml.CreateItemGroupElement();
project.Xml.InsertAfterChild(slItemGroup, project.Xml.LastChild);
slItemGroup.AddItem("Reference", "System.IO");
```

and you have to call save method of your project:

```
project.Save(projectFileName);
```